# classification and prediction Decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

The computational complexity of the algorithm given training set D is O(n*|D|
log(|D|)), where n is the number of attributes describing the tuples in D and |D| is the number of training tuples in D. This means that the computational cost of growing a tree grows at most n *D*log(|D|) with |D| tuples.I am not able to log(|D|)part specifically.
Refrenece-Book Data minning concepts and tech.2nd edition page number 296 
topic-Classification and prediction(Chapter 6)

Answer (score 0):

The height of a balanced tree is at most O(log(n)). Is your tree balanced?

Comment: no!its actully while building a decison tree it may not me a binary tree.

Comment: Also non binary trees have height O(log n), as long as they are not unary.